# Python nested for loop variable 'overwrite'

Tags: python

Sorry for the noob question, but someone pls explain me the inner workings of this nested for loop.

```
v,w = 2,4
for v in range(v):
   for w in range(w):
        print('v=',v,'w=',w)
```

If I run it like this, the output will be as follows:

```
v= 0 w= 0
v= 0 w= 1
v= 0 w= 2
v= 0 w= 3
v= 1 w= 0
v= 1 w= 1
v= 1 w= 2
```

I figured it stops 'prematurely' (the last output v= 1 w= 3 is missing) cause the last value assigned to the 'w' variable was 3 before the last loop ran.

If I run it like this, it works, but doesn't look Pythonic to say the least.

```
v,w = 2,4
for v in range(v):
    for w in range(w):
        print('v=',v,'w=',w)
    w = 4
```

Could some please explain how this problem is best addressed?

Comment: Variables leak from loops. Your `w` ends at 3 after first iteration of outer loop.

Comment: What is the _problem_ ?

Comment: You need to use different temporarily variable during the iteration. For example `for v_ in range(v): for w_ in range(w)`

Answer (score 6):

> I figured it stops 'prematurely' (the last output v= 1 w= 3 is missing) cause the last value assigned to the 'w' variable was 3 before the last loop ran

Correct.

> Could some please explain how this problem is best addressed?

Don't re-use the same local variable name for two different meanings:

```
n_v, n_w = 2, 4
for v in range(n_v):
   for w in range(n_w):
        print('v=', v, 'w=', w)
```

Comment: Was writing this.  In addition, I'd point the OP to http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Although extremely confusing and ugly, if the loops are not nested, re-using the same variable is not an issue. In my opinion this has to be noted.

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting thing to notice here in my opinion is that `range(w)` is not updated **as long as** you stay in the same `for v in range(v)` iteration. And that is why you get:

```
v = 0,  w = 0
v = 0,  w = 1
v = 0,  w = 2
v = 0,  w = 3
```

**But**, on the second iteration, when your `v` becomes `1`, `range(w)` gets **redefined** using the new `w` value which is now `3`. And that is why you then get:

```
v = 1,  w = 0
v = 1,  w = 1
v = 1,  w = 2
```

---

Addressing the problem as for example @wim says is simple; you just have to use different variables:

```
for i in range(v):
    for j in range(w):
        # do your thing
```

---

A side-effect of the above is that the following does execute 5 times even though it is a horrible thing to write:

```
v = 5
for v in range(v):
    # do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Peter see the answer from wim he is correct.

Rewrite the code like below:-

```
v,w = 2,4
  for v1 in range(v):
     for w1 in range(w):
         print('v=',v1,'w=',w1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is known as *variable leaking* in for loops and is due to the fact that Python does not create a new variable in for loops.

At the end of  `for w in range(w):`, `w` has value 3 so when you run the loop again it will run for range(3) and for range(4) with the original value of `w` as you might have expected.

To avoid this, use a different variable for in the `for` loop, as suggested in the other answers.

The only case when the for loop variable is not exposed to the surrounding function is in list comprehensions (and only in Python 3, see [PEP- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)), so for instance

```
>>> for v in range(v):
...    print([('v=',v,'w=',w) for w in range(w)])
...    print(w)
...
[('v=', 0, 'w=', 0), ('v=', 0, 'w=', 1), ('v=', 0, 'w=', 2), ('v=', 0, 'w=', 3)]
4
[('v=', 1, 'w=', 0), ('v=', 1, 'w=', 1), ('v=', 1, 'w=', 2), ('v=', 1, 'w=', 3)]
4
```